# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on requests between 2 local apps

Tags: node.js, angular, http-headers

I am building Angular 8 application (that uses localhost:4200) and this app should GET and POST some JSON data from another app (NodeJS app, that uses localhost:5000) using different endpoints (like localhost:5000/contacts). When I make a call to localhost:5000/contacts -- I get an error
[image]
I tried to make following things to solve that error:
1) I added headers to the response of my datasource app:
`router.get("/contacts", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   const contactsGetResponse = accountingApi.getContacts(req.session.activeTenant.tenantId);
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,OPTIONS');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, \n' +
            'Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-\n' +
            'Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type');
}`
2) added headers to the function that calls the api:

```
public getContacts(){
  public corsHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5000/'
});
let httpOptions;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: this.corsHeaders
  };

  const url = environment.myEndpoint + '/contacts';
  return this.httpClient.get(environment.myEndpoint + '/contacts', httpOptions);
```

}
But I still get this error.
I know there are many similar questions that are already placed here. But nothing still works for me. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm i cors` then 
Use `app.use(cors())` at the backend ,assuming you are using `expressjs` and `app=express()`
the code should look like

```
const app = express()
const cors=require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   res.send()
})
```

Comment: Should I install cors for both apps? or only for the one of them?

Comment: for node,backend only

Comment: It seems like this solution works for me - I installed cors lib, put Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to the response. And it seems like it's working. Will continue testing.